# trying to place image in center (in responsive fashion)

Tags: css

I have tried the following approaches but they do not seem to work for me (I'm sure I am doing something wrong - I need help in figuring out what it is).  The image is in the HTML header section (not body).

1. I have bootstrap in the HEAD section (before the image and it gets picked up from the browser cache so hopefully it gets used for the image in the header)
2. I have tried adding the following to the CSS for the image (and when it did not work, I tried adding a div around the image and assigned the class to the div):

   **display:inline;
   text-align:center;
   margin:auto;**
3. I also tried the following in the CSS when option 2 did not work:

   **display:inline;
   margin:auto;
   horizontal-align:center;**

I tried display:block in place of **display:inline** as well.  Any thoughts on fixing this (specially without relying on bootstrap would be quite welcome).  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't set a margin on an element that is set to `display:inline`.

Here is a great guide that you should read:

http://www.tipue.com/blog/center-a-div/

Answer (score 2):

General css properties for centering elements:

```
{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you for sharing.  I must be doing something wrong but this is not working for me (I tried adding it as a class and used it with both image and when it did not work, I used the class on the div around the image as well.  I definitely need to work on my css skills - once again, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Place the image in a div, and then put text-align:center on the div. That's it.

http://cdpn.io/aDBhq

Comment: thank you for sharing - much appreciated.  This was quite helpful.